# Unable to get images from a link

Tags: html, ios, xpath

I am trying to get images from a linked page in iOS but it is not working.

In this [link](http://www.cinejosh.com/news/3/40889/high-court-dismisses-andhra-poris-case.html), I have the below image tag

```
<img src="/newsimg/newsmainimg/1433410900_andhra-pori.jpg" 
     alt="High Court Dismisses 'Andhra Pori's Case" 
     class="img-responsive center-block visible-xs">
```

and I am trying to get it using the below code

```
NSString *gossipsXpathQueryString = @"//td//img";W
```

What can I change in this string `@"//td//img"` to get the image correctly.

Comment: put this url if its path is static.http://www.cinejosh.com/newsimg/newsmainimg/1433410900_andhra-pori.jpg

Comment: the above url is from xml document

Comment: ok then that will not be static url may change?

Comment: either you can use @Santu C solution or do same load webpage content and get image parent div id which willbe same and get inner image from that div.

Comment: ya i am trying to using the @santh c solution

Comment: Improved grammar and clarified question a bit more. Language, technology names are not required in question title because they are present as part of tag list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check below code -

```
 NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.cinejosh.com/news/3/40889/high-court-dismisses-andhra-poris-case.html"];
    NSString *webData= [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:url];
   // NSLog(@"%@",webData);


    NSError *error = NULL;
    NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"(<img\\s[\\s\\S]*?src\\s*?=\\s*?['\"](.*?)['\"][\\s\\S]*?>)+?"
                                                                           options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive
                                                                             error:&error];

    [regex enumerateMatchesInString:webData
                            options:0
                              range:NSMakeRange(0, [webData length])
                         usingBlock:^(NSTextCheckingResult *result, NSMatchingFlags flags, BOOL *stop) {

                             NSString *img = [webData substringWithRange:[result rangeAtIndex:2]];
                             NSLog(@"img src %@",img);
                         }];
```

You will be get all img src from above code .

Comment: i got images.Thank you very much for helping